# The logic behind this explanation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

[Number 15 is the one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yoT5c.png)

I do not get how the whole process works. I do get that the division yields a remainder of -17, but how is that supposed to be applied to an alternative expression of the original equation?

Comment: $\frac{12}{5} = \frac{10 + 2}{5} = \frac{10}{5} + \frac{2}{5} = 2 + \frac{2}{5}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In normal division, $\frac{34}{5} = 6$ remainder $4$. Or, you could re-express it by dividing the remainder by the original divisor as $6+\frac{4}{5}$. This corresponds directly to what is shown in the book.

$\frac{5x-2}{x+3} = 5$ remainder $-17 = 5 + \frac{-17}{x+3}$

Comment: I finally get it. Thank you so much for the help. I overthought the whole thing.

Comment: It was embarrassingly simple.

Comment: No problem. Please accept the answer if it solved the question. Thanks!